# Login problem with mongo dB on my dynamic website using a Linux based codio server

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, ejs

Can anyone tell my why my login system isn't working on my server? it just returns user not found even though the users table in my mongo DB contains a valid username and password that I use. here is the code I use to try login.

```js
app.post('/dologin', function (req, res) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(req.body))
    var uname = req.body.username;
    var pword = req.body.password;

    db.collection('users').findOne({
        "SignIn.username": uname
    }, function (err, result) {
        if (err) throw err;

        if (!result) {
            res.redirect('/SignIn');
            console.log("user not found :(")
            return
        }

        if (result.SignIn.password == pword) {
            req.session.loggedin = true;
            req.session.currentuser = uname;
            res.redirect('pages/UserAccount')
            console.log("a user was recognised, horay!")
        } else {
            res.redirect('/SignIn')
            console.log("user not found :(")
        }
    });
});
```

this is the form used to take in the username and password it is stored in a file called `SignIn.ejs`:

```html
<form action="/dologin" method="POST">
    <input class="UsernameBox" type="text" placeholder="username"  name="username"> 
    <input class="PasswordBox" type="password" placeholder="password"  name="password">
    <button class="LogInButton" type="submit">login</button> 
</form>
```

the MongoDB stores its username and passwords in a table called users

I need to get this going in the next day so any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: this is the code used to take in the username and password:   <form action="/dologin" method="POST">
    <input class="UsernameBox" type="text" placeholder="username"  name="username"> 
    <input class="PasswordBox" type="password" placeholder="password"  name="password">
    <button class="LogInButton" type="submit">login</button> 
  </form>

Comment: You've logged the stringified `req.body`, how does it look like?